# Can slug and title changes be propagated to multiple sites?

Tags: multi-site, slug

I'm noticing that if I change the title or the slug of an entry after creation, that change isn't propagated to my other Craft sites.  Is there a way to propagate title and slug like other fields?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment I believe this can only be achieved with the site-sync plugin: https://github.com/timkelty/craftcms-site-sync